# How to convert a address to a string ?(16 bit assembly)

Tags: assembly

If i wanted to convert an address like "$" (which represent's the current one) to a string in order to have it displayed to the console, how would i do it?

I've seen many examples of how to do this with other languages, i just haven't seen any that do it in assembly yet.

Comment: The same way as any other integer.

Comment: To me it is not clear what "address" means in this context. Obviously it is not what is normally meant by the word "address" in low level programming.

Comment: To clarify it more, 0x7000 or 7000h or the "$" op code that points to the current address. Addresses are a bit confusing to me.

Comment: The `$` is not an op-code. op-codes are the codes that your processor handles. The `$` is something that your assembler interprets before converting your program into machine code, which your processor is able to read. Thus the assembler will replace this $ with the current address. Be careful, when using other assemblers or a diffrent assembly syntax the $ may have a different meaning.

Comment: thanks for your advice "Blechdose" ill keep this in mind the next time i use the "$" symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little DOS program will display the value of "$" on the screen.
The ouput will be "0100".

```
 ORG     256
 mov     bx,$
 mov     cx,0404h
.again:
 rol     bx,cl
 mov     dl,bl
 and     dl,0000_1111b
 add     dl,'0'
 cmp     dl,'9'
 jbe     .OK
 add     dl,7
.OK:
 mov     ah,02h
 int     21h       ;Print Character
 dec     ch
 jnz     .again
 mov     ax,4C00h
 int     21h       ;Terminate
```

Comment: Thanks, i can't wait to break my noob barrier.